# python plotting 3d contour electric potential

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with plotting 3d contour of electric potential. 
I have measured voltage drops between electrons on 2d foil, saved as a textfile. 
Total 620 point data were taken on a 20*30cm area (it is 620 instead of 600 because I included 0th column), which is only a top right quarter of the foil (so the total foil size is 60*40cm but i only took the right top quarter assuming that the foil would have symmetric voltage difference across, so I can generate rest of the data points on other quarters later). The measurement was started from the top right corner (row20, col 31), along the same row until it reaches column 0, then move back to (row19, col 31), again along the row until it reaches column 0, then back to (row18, col 31) so on. This part does not really matter but I'm just writing to give more detailed info for your information.

then on python, I tried to make this 1D data points into an array shape of (20,31). So z[1] would be the data points for my row[0]'s whole column.

I used meshgrid to generate 2D arrays of x and y coordinate. 
However, when I try to plot (x,y,z), it gives me an error saying 
"ValueError: third arg must be a format string"

I tried to fix this myself but not only I don't understand the meaning of the error and I have already wasted enough time (almost 4hours).

Please help me out guys,. also after figuring this out, any tips for how to make the symmetry version of this data would also be very appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Below are the code and data textile

```
#this code is written to plot 3d contour of electric potential 
#############################################################################
#import module
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
#############################################################################
#read in textfile
V = loadtxt('march6_2d_foli.txt')
V_len = len(V) #length of data
#############################################################################

#create zeros for the electric potential
row=20
column = 31 #size of the top right quotient of 2d foil
z = zeros((row,column))

#x and y coordinates
x = array(range(column))
y = array(range(row))

xx,yy = meshgrid(x,y) #meshgrid for plotting 3d contour

#assigning V on each xy-plane
i = V_len-1 #iterate from backward due to the way that data was taken
for j in range(row):
    #print j
    for k in range(column):
        #print k  
        z[j,k] = V[i]
        i= i-1


#plot 3d contour of potential
fig=figure()
ax =Axes3D(fig)
ax.plot(xx,yy,z)

show()
```

march6_2d_foli.txt

```
                            4.42132344E-4
                            4.41623046E-4
                            4.38102009E-4
                            4.34149584E-4
                            4.28952270E-4
                            4.23666861E-4
                            4.19301767E-4
                            4.11912545E-4
                            4.04893872E-4
                            3.97685520E-4
                            3.87717050E-4
                            3.77126962E-4
                            3.67247688E-4
                            3.53739186E-4
                            3.39005066E-4
                            3.24784097E-4
                            3.07243885E-4
                            2.89085632E-4
                            2.71694355E-4
                            2.53022400E-4
                            2.33087112E-4
                            2.12168190E-4
                            1.91893737E-4
                            1.70294560E-4
                            1.47628059E-4
                            1.22870410E-4
                            9.67236164E-5
                            7.60527370E-5
                            5.21171217E-5
                            2.74706919E-5
                            1.31591513E-6
                            4.48928852E-4
                            4.47514381E-4
                            4.45230801E-4
                            4.41803089E-4
                            4.36100056E-4
                            4.33534022E-4
                            4.26584173E-4
                            4.18988204E-4
                            4.11986049E-4
                            4.03273755E-4
                            3.94718930E-4
                            3.82510376E-4
                            3.71554970E-4
                            3.58908695E-4
                            3.45157657E-4
                            3.29853399E-4
                            3.13157244E-4
                            2.98293459E-4
                            2.80533010E-4
                            2.61448937E-4
                            2.39444523E-4
                            2.20510211E-4
                            1.96615340E-4
                            1.76077428E-4
                            1.52922002E-4
                            1.28869111E-4
                            1.03387708E-4
                            8.05629122E-5
                            5.34030295E-5
                            2.86616227E-5
                            5.37708251E-6
                            4.53625128E-4
                            4.50306159E-4
                            4.45926474E-4
                            4.43933055E-4
                            4.40328604E-4
                            4.36204118E-4
                            4.29921862E-4
                            4.25252015E-4
                            4.14644308E-4
                            4.08848775E-4
                            4.00559887E-4
                            3.90274275E-4
                            3.78377907E-4
                            3.67049199E-4
                            3.53591076E-4
                            3.37341452E-4
                            3.21207176E-4
                            3.05610278E-4
                            2.87921405E-4
                            2.68807876E-4
                            2.46222863E-4
                            2.26484962E-4
                            2.02520440E-4
                            1.80960079E-4
                            1.56737330E-4
                            1.30996874E-4
                            1.06688232E-4
                            8.03842451E-5
                            5.61309381E-5
                            2.80278912E-5
                            4.26020642E-6
                            4.58014723E-4
                            4.55834654E-4
                            4.52538810E-4
                            4.48783496E-4
                            4.45355234E-4
                            4.41623872E-4
                            4.35321794E-4
                            4.30008030E-4
                            4.22231192E-4
                            4.15348515E-4
                            4.13991306E-4
                            4.04830830E-4
                            3.96658116E-4
                            3.85564235E-4
                            3.72429861E-4
                            3.59557568E-4
                            3.44380772E-4
                            3.27938990E-4
                            3.09814599E-4
                            2.90585996E-4
                            2.71342802E-4
                            2.49036664E-4
                            2.28909219E-4
                            2.06369630E-4
                            1.83498309E-4
                            1.61270906E-4
                            1.32752161E-4
                            1.10928893E-4
                            8.65891428E-5
                            4.48369176E-5
                            5.96979491E-6
                            4.59343853E-4
                            4.56838659E-4
                            4.53490233E-4
                            4.51161228E-4
                            4.48604554E-4
                            4.43179845E-4
                            4.38840629E-4
                            4.33321493E-4
                            4.26299517E-4
                            4.18246006E-4
                            4.11589898E-4
                            4.03225028E-4
                            3.90428992E-4
                            3.78675777E-4
                            3.66654700E-4
                            3.51158836E-4
                            3.36771864E-4
                            3.15386316E-4
                            2.96078703E-4
                            2.76834132E-4
                            2.55182648E-4
                            2.33892353E-4
                            2.12328413E-4
                            1.87736492E-4
                            1.61787361E-4
                            1.35457496E-4
                            1.09777605E-4
                            8.72327850E-5
                            5.60819354E-5
                            3.07032182E-5
                            4.34747527E-6
                            4.65294928E-4
                            4.63442736E-4
                            4.60911113E-4
                            4.59016250E-4
                            4.55124390E-4
                            4.51774588E-4
                            4.47540534E-4
                            4.42007910E-4
                            4.35113395E-4
                            4.27845855E-4
                            4.20318435E-4
                            4.11943378E-4
                            3.99578731E-4
                            3.86791230E-4
                            3.72448581E-4
                            3.57917079E-4
                            3.42835535E-4
                            3.24811352E-4
                            3.06835896E-4
                            2.82450722E-4
                            2.62075235E-4
                            2.40471378E-4
                            2.17278236E-4
                            1.94920067E-4
                            1.69441417E-4
                            1.43726288E-4
                            1.15164323E-4
                            9.08997284E-5
                            6.49156352E-5
                            3.54308773E-5
                            8.29549596E-6
                            4.68810183E-4
                            4.67745613E-4
                            4.65794315E-4
                            4.63393458E-4
                            4.61059773E-4
                            4.56687246E-4
                            4.53855000E-4
                            4.48874619E-4
                            4.41902747E-4
                            4.36042520E-4
                            4.29339061E-4
                            4.20277416E-4
                            4.09178305E-4
                            3.98815611E-4
                            3.83715072E-4
                            3.71058886E-4
                            3.52476127E-4
                            3.35237639E-4
                            3.16770780E-4
                            2.97270735E-4
                            2.72341851E-4
                            2.49136321E-4
                            2.24441714E-4
                            1.99637540E-4
                            1.71303795E-4
                            1.47405620E-4
                            1.19048199E-4
                            9.07395061E-5
                            6.28616513E-5
                            3.54785035E-5
                            8.45764534E-6
                            4.76454879E-4
                            4.73869574E-4
                            4.71709050E-4
                            4.70567948E-4
                            4.67019382E-4
                            4.63890918E-4
                            4.62192616E-4
                            4.58905031E-4
                            4.53966220E-4
                            4.47851894E-4
                            4.41273970E-4
                            4.33326724E-4
                            4.22826933E-4
                            4.09843971E-4
                            3.98031843E-4
                            3.83450237E-4
                            3.67483616E-4
                            3.48288048E-4
                            3.27471262E-4
                            3.06656678E-4
                            2.81963999E-4
                            2.57995073E-4
                            2.31786338E-4
                            2.05128870E-4
                            1.80297442E-4
                            1.53216844E-4
                            1.24102084E-4
                            9.62115658E-5
                            6.61448321E-5
                            3.93890840E-5
                            6.71970136E-6
                            4.81063610E-4
                            4.79544802E-4
                            4.78857112E-4
                            4.77290127E-4
                            4.74889270E-4
                            4.73003768E-4
                            4.69474197E-4
                            4.67487110E-4
                            4.62404594E-4
                            4.58941370E-4
                            4.52238737E-4
                            4.45519586E-4
                            4.34350275E-4
                            4.22932921E-4
                            4.10460634E-4
                            3.96225901E-4
                            3.78751759E-4
                            3.62907370E-4
                            3.39854629E-4
                            3.15884602E-4
                            2.90845325E-4
                            2.66215963E-4
                            2.39909498E-4
                            2.13026563E-4
                            1.84919387E-4
                            1.56147646E-4
                            1.27382787E-4
                            9.61697208E-5
                            6.63543324E-5
                            3.72894010E-5
                            8.38689425E-6
                            4.83899159E-4
                            4.83044916E-4
                            4.82070643E-4
                            4.81313304E-4
                            4.80216249E-4
                            4.77632045E-4
                            4.75897955E-4
                            4.74213969E-4
                            4.71581588E-4
                            4.66225428E-4
                            4.61672307E-4
                            4.54264090E-4
                            4.45534452E-4
                            4.35289310E-4
                            4.24485041E-4
                            4.09799373E-4
                            3.91286814E-4
                            3.75526391E-4
                            3.52319759E-4
                            3.27716826E-4
                            3.01915530E-4
                            2.77299382E-4
                            2.50613559E-4
                            2.23088634E-4
                            1.92553622E-4
                            1.61339730E-4
                            1.31309335E-4
                            1.02244128E-4
                            6.87997872E-5
                            3.99517891E-5
                            7.67112452E-6
                            4.84702473E-4
                            4.87576014E-4
                            4.87362384E-4
                            4.87928943E-4
                            4.86856665E-4
                            4.87792947E-4
                            4.85911574E-4
                            4.85702899E-4
                            4.83943757E-4
                            4.80949638E-4
                            4.74987000E-4
                            4.71100921E-4
                            4.62862962E-4
                            4.53590991E-4
                            4.41108793E-4
                            4.26313006E-4
                            4.10045212E-4
                            3.89452241E-4
                            3.68150934E-4
                            3.40809907E-4
                            3.14838477E-4
                            2.82967178E-4
                            2.56238408E-4
                            2.27764538E-4
                            1.97045352E-4
                            1.64360553E-4
                            1.32541835E-4
                            1.03156184E-4
                            6.98984937E-5
                            3.88618920E-5
                            7.93623462E-6
                            4.92532719E-4
                            4.93266383E-4
                            4.95015339E-4
                            4.94513749E-4
                            4.95485820E-4
                            4.97036562E-4
                            4.96583150E-4
                            4.96366767E-4
                            4.96959204E-4
                            4.96642063E-4
                            4.93001823E-4
                            4.88407683E-4
                            4.81939327E-4
                            4.73271631E-4
                            4.62610516E-4
                            4.47010314E-4
                            4.29762191E-4
                            4.07434304E-4
                            3.85409794E-4
                            3.58719567E-4
                            3.31823693E-4
                            3.02865852E-4
                            2.75320830E-4
                            2.41316812E-4
                            2.10995429E-4
                            1.74345541E-4
                            1.40563962E-4
                            1.16500885E-4
                            8.19245265E-5
                            4.59835256E-5
                            1.02734981E-5
                            4.99781539E-4
                            5.01777436E-4
                            5.04522688E-4
                            5.05093652E-4
                            5.05452638E-4
                            5.09035341E-4
                            5.09452414E-4
                            5.11695251E-4
                            5.13698030E-4
                            5.14273399E-4
                            5.12382390E-4
                            5.07743652E-4
                            5.05212855E-4
                            4.94636807E-4
                            4.86350120E-4
                            4.75004619E-4
                            4.56705140E-4
                            4.34816076E-4
                            4.17853434E-4
                            3.83901172E-4
                            3.51621608E-4
                            3.21173590E-4
                            2.84529483E-4
                            2.51626649E-4
                            2.15262518E-4
                            1.79939557E-4
                            1.45274002E-4
                            1.11456635E-4
                            7.72483478E-5
                            4.28112892E-5
                            6.65968682E-6
                            4.92351850E-4
                            5.06306056E-4
                            5.07649776E-4
                            5.11653957E-4
                            5.14141532E-4
                            5.17942269E-4
                            5.20444711E-4
                            5.24165337E-4
                            5.26233085E-4
                            5.29522047E-4
                            5.31267975E-4
                            5.33294154E-4
                            5.30641401E-4
                            5.25862262E-4
                            5.15964267E-4
                            5.03301475E-4
                            4.84695316E-4
                            4.61601556E-4
                            4.33780687E-4
                            4.02123018E-4
                            3.69715441E-4
                            3.32264992E-4
                            2.97108585E-4
                            2.62303731E-4
                            2.26147449E-4
                            1.86416998E-4
                            1.51794665E-4
                            1.16766270E-4
                            8.07498383E-5
                            4.37715218E-5
                            9.10569225E-6
                            5.08118880E-4
                            5.10736671E-4
                            5.13842836E-4
                            5.18763478E-4
                            5.19712423E-4
                            5.25756273E-4
                            5.32776873E-4
                            5.34574831E-4
                            5.40874981E-4
                            5.44189270E-4
                            5.51035608E-4
                            5.54937929E-4
                            5.59886376E-4
                            5.59816451E-4
                            5.52025573E-4
                            5.38595530E-4
                            5.19050887E-4
                            4.94848234E-4
                            4.60515513E-4
                            4.27053553E-4
                            3.85446959E-4
                            3.48169671E-4
                            3.07435491E-4
                            2.69974856E-4
                            2.32989932E-4
                            1.94236782E-4
                            1.59107354E-4
                            1.20622342E-4
                            7.81405823E-5
                            4.33357282E-5
                            8.00450804E-6
                            5.14195490E-4
                            5.15604455E-4
                            5.22030966E-4
                            5.22514937E-4
                            5.27298206E-4
                            5.33316177E-4
                            5.39640003E-4
                            5.48121049E-4
                            5.52540376E-4
                            5.61732511E-4
                            5.70537030E-4
                            5.80111276E-4
                            5.84721384E-4
                            5.89484831E-4
                            5.87430297E-4
                            5.77258933E-4
                            5.52126606E-4
                            5.28202003E-4
                            4.85672617E-4
                            4.47897869E-4
                            4.06433603E-4
                            3.60883118E-4
                            3.22212832E-4
                            2.85482833E-4
                            2.41778483E-4
                            2.03069381E-4
                            1.61366984E-4
                            1.24143103E-4
                            8.32594371E-5
                            4.67108578E-5
                            1.00301364E-5
                            5.16680037E-4
                            5.18535257E-4
                            5.20887111E-4
                            5.26818915E-4
                            5.32365030E-4
                            5.39855560E-4
                            5.47702599E-4
                            5.56094724E-4
                            5.66541933E-4
                            5.79722007E-4
                            5.91440810E-4
                            6.06260547E-4
                            6.18750178E-4
                            6.31153366E-4
                            6.31054810E-4
                            6.21120477E-4
                            6.01512240E-4
                            5.65308332E-4
                            5.20886010E-4
                            4.72155030E-4
                            4.23078553E-4
                            3.76263633E-4
                            3.33890616E-4
                            2.91985876E-4
                            2.47776634E-4
                            2.08934288E-4
                            1.66638353E-4
                            1.28570139E-4
                            8.94178098E-5
                            4.77093566E-5
                            5.11279830E-6
                            5.19722334E-4
                            5.23450393E-4
                            5.26679891E-4
                            5.33462360E-4
                            5.39137588E-4
                            5.45288252E-4
                            5.55650396E-4
                            5.67487851E-4
                            5.79078090E-4
                            5.94133756E-4
                            6.11924488E-4
                            6.32301902E-4
                            6.56040680E-4
                            6.77705929E-4
                            6.95398931E-4
                            6.90897565E-4
                            6.58926609E-4
                            6.16067418E-4
                            5.59507018E-4
                            5.05196888E-4
                            4.49724458E-4
                            3.93161856E-4
                            3.49412358E-4
                            3.01478084E-4
                            2.56344673E-4
                            2.13549351E-4
                            1.66747370E-4
                            1.31140028E-4
                            8.75972770E-5
                            5.02528168E-5
                            7.71737425E-6
                            5.20499219E-4
                            5.53256421E-4
                            5.28934015E-4
                            5.36354069E-4
                            3.19752511E-4
                            3.52163391E-4
                            4.09909766E-4
                            4.49174417E-4
                            6.29300899E-4
                            4.59928857E-4
                            4.75104276E-4
                            5.42272659E-4
                            4.60129823E-4
                            5.29001738E-4
                            4.20211069E-4
                            3.80738020E-4
                            6.90785520E-4
                            6.46286115E-4
                            5.70236957E-4
                            4.98514902E-4
                            4.45782769E-4
                            4.06978414E-4
                            3.41247352E-4
                            2.80391508E-4
                            2.01609486E-4
                            2.09571873E-4
                            1.42826345E-4
                            7.61102739E-5
                            9.03026113E-5
                            4.44853645E-5
                            1.19537125E-4
                            5.22289194E-4
                            5.24706293E-4
                            5.28508132E-4
                            3.79107442E-4
                            3.41947980E-4
                            3.18995447E-4
                            3.52016658E-4
                            3.69091621E-4
                            5.40337053E-4
                            6.07468546E-4
                            6.45454996E-4
                            6.62478754E-4
                            7.10152872E-4
                            7.73804073E-4
                            8.63135990E-4
                            9.24004498E-4
                            8.34513735E-4
                            7.31465467E-4
                            6.31526943E-4
                            5.42251186E-4
                            4.70062229E-4
                            4.10128076E-4
                            3.55851257E-4
                            2.98828635E-4
                            2.66038397E-4
                            2.18243974E-4
                            1.72832514E-4
                            1.31930403E-4
                            8.78431164E-5
                            4.71502303E-5
                            9.42448508E-6
```

Comment: Try `ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')` instead of `ax=Axis3D(fig)`

Comment: @Lucas  thank you Lucas that actually worked.. but what was the error implying?

Comment: It's thrown because they've changed the way matplotlib works in recent versions. I'm not sure about the details of the error without a stack trace.